# Гібридна війна українською

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Відомо, що "гібрид" та всі слова утворені від нього - [запозичені слова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4). На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/hibryd) я зустрів відповідник до слова "гібрид" - "[покруч](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokruchenyj)", яке насправді є в СУМі та, на мою думку, чудово замінює це слово.

Однак, як бути із словосполученням "[гібридна війна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)", адже "покруч" означає: "Потомство, виведене від схрещування різних порід тварин, видів рослин", тобто, коли ми говоримо про зоологію чи ботаніку, то все гаразд, але  чи буде доречно його вживати, коли ми говоримо про війну? І яке словосполучення ми отримаємо? Покручена війна?

Comment: Для _гібрид_, по-моєму, найкраще підходить заміна _[по́місь](http://sum.in.ua/s/pomisj)_. Бо _по́круч_, на відміну від _гібри́д_, має здебільшого негативну конотацію.

Comment: Як щодо _змі́шана_, _комбіно́вана_, _різнобі́чна_, _різнове́кторна_, _різноли́ка_, _різнома́ста_, _різнопла́нова_, _різнорі́дна_, _різносторо́ння_, _різноти́пна_, _різнохара́ктерна_, _різношля́хова війна_?

Comment: В такому випадку, найкращим варіантом, напевно, буде "змішана війна"

Answer (score 1):

[Словник Павла Штепи](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt):

> *гібрид* — покруч, тума, суржик, (вона) суржанка, див. метис, ублюдок
>
> *гібридизація* — суржа
>
> *гібридизувати* — суржити, висуржувати, висурдити, повисуржувати, зісуржувати, зісурдити, позісуржувати, посуржувати, посурдити, усуржувати, усурдити, повсуржувати

І, як на мене, *покручна війна* цілком собі звучить. Дивіть не тільки першу цятку:

> 4. *перев. мн., перен., рідко.* Відхилення в розвитку чого-небудь. *Чудні слова [іншомовні] тільки пробуджували в його дитячій голові часом якісь незвичайно чудні покручі мислі...* (Нечуй-Левицький, I, 1956, 174

Для доповнення: [московсько-украӥньський словник](//russian_ukrainian.academic.ru/15455/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

> *гибридный* — гібридний, мішаний, покручний

Також зазначу, що саме слово [hybrid](//en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)) теж стосується передусім біолоґії.

Comment: Але ж _гібридна війна_ — це саме змішана війна (що ведеться різними шляхами одночасно, часто деякими з них напівприховано). Тому оце четверте значення («відхилення»), як і вся негативна конотація слова _покруч_, по-моєму, навпаки, **заважає**.

Comment: @Sasha Тодьі бажано мати точне визначенньа, а то матимемо _"неконвенційна війна" (unconventional warfare), "нерегулярна війна" (irregular warfare) чи "змішана війна" (**compound** warfare), або ж спонсоровані державою "гібридні війни" (State-Sponsored Hybrid)._